# checkbox value unidentified

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm new to web development and working on simple projects and I am stuck on a problem if anyone can help. I have a 3 checkboxes that a user can check on what their favourite things are to do. After completing the question I am trying to log the value of the chosen boxes however I am getting unidentified results if anyone can help id be grateful. This is the code:
html:

```
What is your favorite thing to do:
    <p id = "favoriteThings">
        <input type="checkbox" name="TV" value=1>Watch TV
        <input type="checkbox" name="Books" value=2>Read Books
        <input type="checkbox" name="work" value=3>Work
    </p>
```

JS:

```
var favoriteThings = document.getElementById("favoriteThings");
console.log("favorite things: " + favoriteThings.value);
```

I am assuming that the problem is the paragraph tag is the ID but can someone give me a fix to this? As I don't want to give each checkbox the same ID as I heard its bad practice.
thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you are getting the value (undefined) of a <p> element, which has not value. You can give IDs to all of the 3 inputs, then getting their values ("checked" boolean attribute, not "value") as you are doing now. Anyway, it looks like you're trying to realize a custom made radio button: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

Comment: And don't use w3schools as your source of truth. Still at this date (almost 2022) it's the worst website to learn to code from. It's not a community-driven website, it's full of bad practice examples, and they sell irrelevant certificates.

Answer (score 0):

- When you want to *group* your checkbox (or radio) inputs, use the same `name` for your group of [inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)
- Use a different `value`
- Use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get your desired elements using the Attribute selector `"[]"`
- Use [nodeList.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to iterate your elements
- Use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach an Event, `"input"` in your case:

```js
const ELs_favorite = document.querySelectorAll("[name=favorite]");

const get_favorite = () => {
  const checked_values = [...ELs_favorite].reduce((arr, EL) => {
    if (EL.checked) arr.push(EL.value);
    return arr;
  }, []);
  console.log(checked_values);
};

ELs_favorite.forEach(EL => {
  EL.addEventListener("input", get_favorite);
});
```

```html
What is your favorite thing to do:
<p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="favorite" value="tv">Watch TV</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="favorite" value="books">Read Books</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="favorite" value="work">Work</label>
</p>
```

In the example above, [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is used to collect only the `value`s of the `checked` input elements into an Array.

Answer (score -1):

you can give each checkbox the same id (there is no problem).

**Solution:**

```
    <p id = "favoriteThings">
        <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteThings" value="TV" or "1" onclick="MyNameFunction()">Watch TV
        <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteThings" value="Read Books" or "2"  onclick="MyNameFunction()">Read Books
        <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteThings" value="Work" or "3"  onclick="MyNameFunction()">Work
    </p>
```

js

```
    var choices = [];
    var els = document.getElementsByName('favoriteThings');
    console.log("Favourite things: ");
    for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    if ( els[i].checked ) {
     console.log(els[i].value);
    }
```

Comment: Stop using unsafe inline `on*` attributes, same as you hopefully don't use inline `style` attribute. JS, same as CSS should be in one place only, and that's in their respective tags or files.

Comment: I know. But I put it because in this situation is clear what is mean!